# Defining a universal property

Tags: category-theory, definition, universal-property

I was recently introduced to category theory and am looking to verify (proof?) a universal property from a diagram as shown.

[image]

In this example, the description says:
Take a topological space covered by two open subsets: $X = U \cup V$. The diagram of inclusion maps has a universal property in the world of topological spaces and continuous maps.

***Attempt at verifying a universal property:***

Let $f: U → Y$ and
$g : V → Y$ be any continuous functions so that $f \circ i$ = $g \circ j$. Then there exists a unique continuous function $h : X → Y$ such that $h \circ i' =g$ and $h \circ j' = f$ so that the diagram commutes.

I'd appreciate if someone could guide me on the right track towards my first verification of universal property.

Answer (score 3):

If you have continuous functions $f: U\to Y$ and $g: V\to Y$ you  can define $h:U\cup V\to Y$ as follows
$$
h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & x\in U\\
g(x) & x\in V
\end{cases}
$$
I'll leave it to you to show that, given the conditions of your problem, $h$ is well-defined and continuous.

In the more general language of category theory, your diagram is a special case of a **pushout** (look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory))) in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks for ur input! Much appreciated.

Comment: Could you define what u mean by "well-defined"

Comment: The way I defined $h$, it is not necessarily a function. Take a point $x\in U\cap V$. Then where does $x$ go? $f(x)$ or $g(x)$? If $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for some point $x\in U\cap V$, then $h$ is not a function. You need to check, therefore, that this does not happen.