# Is this set open? $f^{-1}(V'\cap f(U))$

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I was working through the details of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439374/defining-a-universal-property) I saw earlier when I encountered Hamed's answer. I was wondering how would one show $h$ is continuous?

I had a go as follows:

Suppose $V'\subseteq Y$ is open, I would like to show $h^{-1}(V')$ would also be open. Now we have $$h^{-1}(V')=h^{-1}(V'\cap f(U)) \cup h^{-1}(V'\cap g(V))=f^{-1}(V'\cap f(U)) \cup g^{-1}(V'\cap g(V)).$$
Now it would be very nice that $f^{-1}(V'\cap f(U))$ is open then the union of two open sets is still open but I cannot see why this set should be open. So in short, my question is the following:

**Question:** Suppose $f:U\to Y$ is a continuous function and take $V'\subseteq Y$ an open set, then is it the case that $f^{-1}(V'\cap f(U))$ is still open?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If $U$ is the domain of $f$ then $f^{-1}(A\cap f(U))=f^{-1}(A)$ for every subset $A$ of its codomain.

Comment: @drhab Ahh I see! Thank you so much for pointing it out! it was silly of me to miss that